# What is Apple's Recycling Program?

Tags: macbook-pro, recycle

Can anyone explain Apple's recycling program to me, and how that plays out when ordering online? I am going to buy a new MacBook Pro and want to trade-in or recycle my old one.

I have a Early 2015 MacBook Pro (Core i5). It got a swollen battery and a line of dead pixel on the display. It has gone through some rough times. I think it can't be traded in but can be recycled from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although related, Apple recycling program and Trade-in program are slightly different.

Apple recycling program primarily concerns with providing an avenue to recycle used hardware in an environmentally responsible way. It also gives Apple the opportunity to reuse certain components again.

You are generally not paid when you recycle old/used products. It's more about an ethically appropriate way to give away unusable hardware.

Apple trade-in program on the other hand lets you receive store-credit in eligible countries in exchange for a working hardware.

As you have a working Mac, you should go ahead with trade-in by visiting the trade-in homepage here:

- [Apple Trade In](https://www.apple.com/shop/trade-in)

You'll be presented with a questionnaire that lets Apple verity the eligibility for trade-in. You start by providing your Mac's serial number which will help Apple determine the system type and configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Based on your responses, Apple will either show you an estimate of the store credit that can be availed, or suggest you to recycle the device.

[image]

[image]

You can locate the Apple trade-in or recycling webpage for your specific country by visiting the [Apple Recycling Programs](https://www.apple.com/recycling/nationalservices/) homepage.

Comment: Can you trade-in or recycle at a physical Apple Store or is it all through online and shipping?

Comment: @SakibulAlam Has to be done at a physical store.

Answer (score 0):

The [Apple Recycling Program](https://www.apple.com/shop/trade-in) is where you can turn in your electronic device and either:

- get a credit on your *next* purchase
- an Apple gift card you can use any time
- if not eligible for credit, they will recycle the components for free

You current order isn’t affected by the trade in credit.  The program varies by country so be certain to review the one specific to your location:

https://www.apple.com/recycling/nationalservices/